# DSACryptoServiceProvider: VerifySignature vs. SignData

Tags: c#, sign, dsa

I'm trying to use the `DSACryproServiceProvider`.
But im a bit confused, because I can't see the Difference between

a) `dsa.VerifySignature()`

b) `dsa.VerifyData()`

Additionaly I expect that `dsa.CreateSignature()` just creates the signature for the given data while `dsa.SignData()` returns the signed data. Is this correct?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `CreateSignature` expects a hashed value. It doesn't perform hashing, and similarly, `VerifySignature` expects a hashed value to verify. This can be used if you want a custom hash, for example.

`SignData` and `VerifyData` perform hashing on the data buffer. The hash itself is `SHA1`, quoting:

> DSA uses the SHA1 hash algorithm.

`DSACryptoServiceProvider` is a bit old though, and if you can, you should use `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Newer asymmetric algorithms are available. Consider using the RSACryptoServiceProvider class instead of the DSACryptoServiceProvider class. Use DSACryptoServiceProvider only for compatibility with legacy applications and data.